# Check if all items from list have been sent for parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scrapy

This is example code:

```
boxes = sel.xpath("//div[@class='lister-item mode-advanced']")
for box in boxes:
    link = box.xpath(".//div[@class='lister-item-image float-left']/a/@href").extract_first()
    absolute_url = response.urljoin(link)
    yield SeleniumRequest(url=absolute_url, callback=self.parse_example)
```

Please tell me, how do this?

```
if all items (links from boxes) have been sent to self.parse_example: 
    ... do something 
else: 
    pass
```

Maybe I need to use `while` ? If yes how do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use the `meta` dict to pass along all the links to a callback which would then take action when the list is empty:

```
def thing_one():
    boxes = sel.xpath("//div[@class='lister-item mode-advanced']")
    box_urls = []
    for box in boxes:
        link = box.xpath(".//div[@class='lister-item-image float-left']/a/@href").extract_first()
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(link)
        box_urls.append(absolute_url)
    # use the first one to get started
    box0 = box_urls.pop()
    yield SeleniumRequest(url=box0, callback=self.parse_example,
                          meta={'box_urls': box_urls})

def parse_example(self, response):
     box_urls = response.meta.get('box_urls')
     if not box_urls:
         self.log('I have seen them all, now time for action!')

     box = box_urls.pop()
     yield SeleniumRequest(url=box, callback=self.parse_example,
                           meta={'box_urls': box_urls})
```

That has the unfortunate side-effect of causing them to be executed serially, but has the pleasing side effect of not requiring any external coordination system such as a database or worse